# Any HTML5 localstorage wrapper?

Tags: html, nosql, local-storage

Any library to support

- CURD
- Get a list, skip, limit
- Filter by field

Or should we use this as NoSql database?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use it as a NoSQL database personally, but I'm sure you could modify this to work with it on smallish scale applications:

http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try CarboStorage:

http://carbogrid.com/index.php/storage/home

Answer (score 0):

I recently was up against the same question, and ended up writing my own:

http://morgul.github.io/dustbin/

It's heavily influenced by Riak, completely unit-tested, and about as simple as I can make it. Works well for my use cases.

If there's enough demand, I've even got a proposal for adding Link support similar to Riak. It would not be hard; I just need someone who uses it to weigh in on the [proposal](https://github.com/Morgul/dustbin/issues/5).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it was one of the first I came across in a google search for this type of thing. The one I wound up going with is called 'StoreJS'. You can find it here. It currently has 4,250 stars on GitHub, which is awesome.

https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/